# Bash script for querying database with changeable time range

Tags: bash, influxdb

I'm trying to write a bash script that would query InfluxDB database.

The query is the following:

```
select * INTO telegraf.aggregated_1m.net FROM telegraf_agregat_bak.aggregat_1m_bak.net WHERE time > '2020-03-17T13:00' AND time <= '2020-03-20T13:00' GROUP BY *
```

I'd like to run it every 15 minutes which I can do with sleep command. The thing is that I need to change the time range in the query every time the script runs. So in the query would be different time range if you get me :D

```
#!/bin/bash
while true
do
   now="$(date +%s%3N)"
   number="$((1 + RANDOM % 10))"
   echo "Welcome $i times. $number"
   curl -G -XPOST 'http://localhost:8086/query?pretty=true' --data-urlencode "db=telegraf_agregat_bak" --data-urlencode "q= SELECT * INTO telegraf.aggregated_1m.net FROM telegraf_agregat_bak.aggregat_1m_bak.net WHERE time > '2020-03-17' AND time <= '2020-03-20' GROUP BY *"
   sleep 15m
done
```

Thanks for any suggestions on that topic!

Answer (score 1):

You can use variables in bash:

```
...
sleep "$1"
...
```

And use script like:

```
$ ./script.sh 15m
```